# 'strcpy' error and warning

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm getting a 'strcpy' error and warning for the following lines:

```
_tcscpy(strCommandLine,_T("MyProgram.exe /param1"));

_tcscpy(strApplicationName,_T("MyProgram.exe"));
```

Not sure why I'm getting a 'strcpy' error or warning since I'm not using 'strcpy'. The only lines related to this is:

```
LPCTSTR strApplicationName;
LPTSTR strCommandLine;
_tcscpy(strCommandLine,_T("MyProgram.exe /param1"));   //warning is on this line     
_tcscpy(strApplicationName,_T("MyProgram.exe"));       //error is on this line
```

The output is:

```
1>c:\documents and settings\X.X\my documents\sandbox\sample.cpp(52) : warning C4996: 'strcpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strcpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.

1>        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\string.h(74) : see declaration of 'strcpy'

1>c:\documents and settings\X.X\my documents\sandbox\sample.cpp(53) : error C2664: 'strcpy' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'LPCTSTR' to 'char *'

1>        Conversion loses qualifiers
```

Any ideas on what this could means?

These are my headers:

```
iostream
windows.h
stdio.h
tchar.h
winnt.h
```

Answer (score 1):

`LPCTSTR` means a `const` TCHAR pointer. The first argument of _tcscpy expects a non-const TCHAR pointer i.e `LPTSTR`.

Try something like this:

```
TCHAR strApplicationName[2000];
TCHAR strCommandLine[2000[;
_tcscpy(strCommandLine,_T("MyProgram.exe /param1"));   //warning is on this line     
_tcscpy(strApplicationName,_T("MyProgram.exe"));
```

PS: Even this is most probably incorrect. Give us more context (more surrounding code) and we will be able to help you better.

Comment: +1 For not strcpy'ing into random pointers. Second the request for more information - maybe `std::string` would work.

Answer (score 1):

`LPCTSTR` is a typedef name for a pointer to a *constant* string. You can't copy anything to a constant string.

As for the warnings, this is something Microsoft compiler puts out in its own accord. If you want to use `strcpy`, disable the warning. The message itself tells you how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

`strcpy` copies characters until it hits a `\0` null terminator. This can cause buffer overruns and other badness. `strcpy_s` copies only the specified number of characters, so you can tell it to stop copying before it overruns the buffer. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td1esda9(VS.80).aspx for details.

Comment: The `strcpy` is hidden beneath macros or so here; as the OP mentioned, they get the warning for something that's not `strcpy`.

Comment: And I think it would be better to use strncpy as that's standard C++ rather than strcpy_s which seems to be a MS thing.

Answer (score 0):

The warning tells you that `strcpy` is deprecated (obviously `_tcscpy` calls `strcpy`).

The first parameter of `_tcscpy` is the destination string, so it can't be constant. The 'C' in `LPCTSTR` means `const`.

Comment: I don't think so. The warning message says:
    error C2664: 'strcpy' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'LPCTSTR' to 'char *'
    Conversion loses qualifiers"